Progress Cards - how many of each exist?
What is the Progress Card composition in a copy of Catan: C&K that's unadulterated and not missing any of the pieces?
That is, how many of each progress card are supposed to exist — how many Diplomat, how many Irrigation, etc.?

In the base game, there are 25 development cards: 14 knight cards, 5 victory point cards, 2 road building, 2 year of plenty, and 2 monopoly.
…
Catan: Cities & Knights … uses Progress cards. These are generated through a combination of city improvements and dice rolls but function much the same as regular development cards.
–“Development cards”, World of Catan Wiki


54 Progress Cards (18 Science Cards, 18 Politics Cards, 18 Trade Cards)
–“CATAN: Cities & Knights”, §Contents, Board Game Geek Community Wiki


Using the same wiki you used in your question, the breakdown looks like this
18 Science Cards (Green):

2 Alchemist
2 Crane
1 Engineer
2 Inventor
2 Irrigation
2 Medicine
2 Mining
1 Printer
2 Road Building
2 Smith

18 Politics Cards (Blue):

2 Bishop
1 Constitution
2 Deserter
2 Diplomat
2 Intrigue
2 Saboteur
3 Spy
2 Warlord
2 Wedding

18 Trade Cards (Yellow):

2 Commercial Harbor
2 Master Merchant
6 Merchant
2 Merchant Fleet
4 Resource Monopoly
2 Trade Monopoly

for a total of 54 progress cards

Wow, I even tried searching for "Progress Card" in case the information was on a different page. Can't believe I overlooked checking the expansion page itself.
